# How can the Bootstrap be fixed so that it doesn't mess up the Signin Form and the Footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

This is kind of a follow up to my previous question, but I've been having some trouble lately with the formatting of the footer on the home page and the signin form on a separate page. It seems like the bootstrap at the top of the page is somehow messing with them? But it doesn't affect any other elements. How would I fix this?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=15DKhs1-y_c6C5TXfbQ1es1cJYwItjKkQ" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" > 
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="mainfooter" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="footer-middle">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>Solutions</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Influencers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Partnerships</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cookie Collection</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>Company</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Values</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <h4>Connect</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reddit</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA 
            <ul class="social-network social-circle">
              <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>       
            -->     
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 copy">
        <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright 2021 - website.  All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background: #ebf4fa;
  /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  background: linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A); */
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

footer a {
  color: #818494;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #030929;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;
  color: #030929;
}







/* LOGIN */

/* FORM */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
input {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 8vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.forms-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.signin-signup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 75%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s 0.7s ease-in-out;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  z-index: 5;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

form.sign-in-form {
  z-index: 2;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #444;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #acacac;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.input-field input {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #333;
}

.input-field input::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.social-text {
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.social-media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}



.btn {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #11aadd;
}
.panels-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 2000px;
  top: -10%;
  right: 48%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #00BFFF 0%, #04befe 100%);
  transition: 1.8s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1.1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

.left-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
  padding: 3rem 17% 2rem 12%;
}

.right-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 3rem 12% 2rem 17%;
}

.panel .content {
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
}

.btn.transparent {
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 130px;
  height: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.right-panel .image,
.right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(800px);
}

/* ANIMATION */

.container.sign-up-mode:before {
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  right: 52%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(-800px);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
  left: 25%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.sign-in-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
}

@media (max-width: 870px) {
  .container {
    min-height: 800px;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .signin-signup {
    width: 100%;
    top: 95%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    transition: 1s 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }

  .signin-signup,
  .container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
    left: 50%;
  }

  .panels-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }

  .panel {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2.5rem 8%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }

  .right-panel {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }

  .left-panel {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .image {
    width: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .panel .content {
    padding-right: 15%;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .panel h3 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .panel p {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
  }

  .btn.transparent {
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1500px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 68%;
    right: initial;
    top: initial;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
    bottom: 32%;
    right: initial;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(-300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  .right-panel .image,
  .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
    top: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
  form {
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
  }

  .image {
    display: none;
  }
  .panel .content {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    bottom: 72%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    bottom: 28%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

signin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signin.css" />
    <title>Login & Sign up Form</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav>
      <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
      <!-- <div class="logo">logo</div> -->
      <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="logo.png"></a>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#problem">Problem</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="signin.html">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <label for="nav-toggle" class="icon-burger">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </label>
    </nav>


<!-- SIGNIN -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="forms-container">
        <div class="signin-signup">
          <form action="#" class="sign-in-form">
            <h2 class="title">Login</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
            <p class="social-text">Or Login with social platforms</p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
          <form action="#" class="sign-up-form">
            <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
            <p class="social-text">Or Sign up with social platforms</p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panels-container">
        <div class="panel left-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>New here ?</h3>
            <p>
              We're your go-to platform for ___
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">
              Sign up
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel right-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>One of us ?</h3>
            <p>
              We're glad that you value __. 
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="register.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

signin.css:

```
/* navbar code carried over from previous file */

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background: #ebf4fa;
  /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  background: linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A); */
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

footer a {
  color: #818494;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #030929;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;
  color: #030929;
}


/*SOCİAL İCONS*/

/* footer social icons */

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}






/* LOGIN */

/* FORM */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
input {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 8vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.forms-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.signin-signup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 75%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s 0.7s ease-in-out;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  z-index: 5;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

form.sign-in-form {
  z-index: 2;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #444;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #acacac;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.input-field input {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #333;
}

.input-field input::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.social-text {
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.social-media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-icon {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0.45rem;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  color: #00BFFF;
  border-color: #00BFFF;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #11aadd;
}
.panels-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 2000px;
  top: -10%;
  right: 48%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #00BFFF 0%, #04befe 100%);
  transition: 1.8s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1.1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

.left-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
  padding: 3rem 17% 2rem 12%;
}

.right-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 3rem 12% 2rem 17%;
}

.panel .content {
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
}

.btn.transparent {
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 130px;
  height: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.right-panel .image,
.right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(800px);
}

/* ANIMATION */

.container.sign-up-mode:before {
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  right: 52%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(-800px);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
  left: 25%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.sign-in-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
}

@media (max-width: 870px) {
  .container {
    min-height: 800px;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .signin-signup {
    width: 100%;
    top: 95%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    transition: 1s 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }

  .signin-signup,
  .container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
    left: 50%;
  }

  .panels-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }

  .panel {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2.5rem 8%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }

  .right-panel {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }

  .left-panel {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .image {
    width: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .panel .content {
    padding-right: 15%;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .panel h3 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .panel p {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
  }

  .btn.transparent {
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1500px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 68%;
    right: initial;
    top: initial;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
    bottom: 32%;
    right: initial;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(-300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  .right-panel .image,
  .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .signin-signup {
    top: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
  form {
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
  }

  .image {
    display: none;
  }
  .panel .content {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    bottom: 72%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    bottom: 28%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try re-arranging your head tag, such that your style.css or any personal css files come below bootstrap files (or come last if possible). Something like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=15DKhs1-y_c6C5TXfbQ1es1cJYwItjKkQ" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  </head>
```

Hope it was useful. Goodluck.

Comment: Just added the changes to the header code and the footer still remains the same, except the navbar moves to the left.

Comment: hi, i looked through the code and didn't really find the styling for the navbar. also can you explain how exactly your footer is being affected?

Comment: Yes! So it looks like the signin animation is on top of the footer for some reason. I wonder if that's because of the Bootstrap or for some other reason.

Comment: Not sure how I'd show you the rest of the code, the text space for this question is all filled  up :((

Comment: maybe take the animation styles out of the css file and into a style tag in the html..and then debug from there? seperately, it should be easy to find what's wrong.

Comment: That fixed the problem! I think I'll just leave the styling for the signin form and the main page in separate css files.

Comment: How would the Bootstrap affect the spacing of the signin page though? The left and right margins are both compressed inwards.

Comment: Glad i could help!   Change the div with class container to container-fluid, and change the styling for :before element also to container-fluid:before, so you don't loose your arch thingy.